# Reverse String but keep character pairs together

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, reverse

I have analysed the global header of a PCAP file and found out that the magic number is: **d4 c3 b2 a1**

This means that it uses a little endian and all the bytes that come after it need to processed in reverse order. The other sections of the global header are as follows:

```
major version =  02 00

minor version =  04 00

time zone =  00 00 00 00

timestamp =  00 00 00 00

snaplen =  ff ff 00 00

linktype =  01 00 00 00
```

However given that little endian is in use, it should be:

```
major version =  00 02

minor version =  00 04

time zone =  00 00 00 00

timestamp =  00 00 00 00

snaplen =  00 00 ff ff

linktype =  00 00 00 01
```

So I need a way to reverse the string but still keep the pairs of characters separated by the spaces in the same order.

So the code [::-1] will not work because it transforms **02 00** into 00 20, whereas it needs to be **00 02**

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You mean in the ASCII strings in your question, or the actual bytes in a PCAP binary capture? The latter needs knowledge about the width of each byte field in the binary format.

Comment: Why are you converting to hex first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a few more steps to do it:

```
linktype = "00 00 00 01"
rev_linktype = " ".join(reversed(linktype.split()))
```

The idea is to first chop the string into tokens instead of characters, then reverse the order of the tokens, and then join them back into one long string.

Comment: beat me to it :(

Comment: in case you prefer, `" ".join(linktype.split()[::-1])` is the same but save you a few keystrokes

Answer (score 2):

It's unusual to process *hex values* instead of the actual data. *Usually* people would process data that's stored in `bytes` objects, which looks like:

```
major_version =  b"\x02\x00"
minor_version =  b"\x04\x00"
time_zone =  b"\x00\x00\x00\x00"
timestamp =  b"\x00\x00\x00\x00"
snaplen =  b"\xff\xff\x00\x00"
linktype =  b"\x01\x00\x00\x00"
```

I'd recommend storing your your constants as numbers:

```
major_version = 0x02_00
minor_version = 0x04_00
time_zone = 0x00_00_00_00
timestamp = 0x00_00_00_00
snaplen = 0xff_ff_00_00
linktype = 0x01_00_00_00
```

because then you can do:

```
if magic_bytes == b"\xd4\xc3\xb2\xa1":
    endianness = "little"
else:
    endianness = "big"

# a little while later, when we need to use the major version number:
major_version.to_bytes(2, endianness)  # major version takes up 2 bytes
```

There's also an `int.from_bytes`, in case you were wondering! Python solves your problem for you, and faster than you can do it by hand.